# Combox jquery php

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

tengo un combox de 3 niveles, me trae solo primero el siguiente me muestra vacio
aqui el codigo

select

```
< select id="estado" name="estado" class="form-control" >

    < option value="0">Estado< /option>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id_estado'].'">'.$row['estado'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</ select></br>

< select id="municipio" name="municipio" class="form-control">

    <option value='0'>Municipio</option>
</select></br>
< select id="id_parroquia" name="id_parroquia" class="form-control">
     < option value="0">Parroquia< /option>
< /select>
```

el script de jquery

```
    < script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#estado").change(function () {

                $('#id_parroquia').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');

                $("#estado option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_estado = $(this).val();
                    $.post("getMunicipio.php", { id_estado: id_estado }, function(data){
                        $("#municipio").html(data);
                    });            
                });
            })
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#municipio").change(function () {
                $("#municipio option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_municipio = $(this).val();
                    $.post("getLocalidad.php", { id_municipio: id_municipio }, function(data){
                        $("#id_parroquia").html(data);
                    });            
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

aqui trae el id_estado para buscar el municipio
    require('../modelo/conexion1.php');

```
$id_estado = $_POST['id_estado'];

$queryM = "SELECT id_municipio, municipio FROM municipio WHERE id_estado = '$id_estado'";
$resultadoM = mysql_query($queryM);

$html= "<option value='0'>Municipio</option>";

while($rowM = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoM));
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$rowM['id_estado']."'>".$rowM['municipio']."</option>";
}

echo $html;
```

y aqui trae el id_municipio para buscar la parroquia

```
$id_municipio = $_POST['id_municipio'];

$query = "SELECT id_municipio, parroquia FROM parroquia WHERE id_municipio = '$id_municipio'";
$resultado=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado));
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$row['id_parroquia']."'>".$row['parroquia']."</option>";
}
echo $html;
```

no se donde es el error si pueden ayudarme

Comment: Hola buenos dias,   el resultado de la consulta de las  parroquias donde estas  pasando el id de municipio, te esta devolviendo algun resultado o es null en caso que sea null verifica que te este pasando el id de municipio a la consulta y no se te este generando  ningun error en ella.

Comment: solo me funciona el primer select del estado, el del municipio no funcion y el de parroquia tampoco funciona

Comment: Para que vallas depuerando el error, verifica que tu codigo php se esta ejecutando correctamente  y que la consulta te este devolviendo los valores deseado. Si todo esta correcto verifica el jquery, primero que te este capturando el valor del id del select y despues que se este  pasando al script php del servidor. Los datos que imprimes en el script de php los almacena en la variale **data** del jquey que los puedes ver con alert(data). Comprueba estos datos por favor.

Comment: el alert(data) solo me sale esto <option value='0'>Municipio</option><option value=''></option>

Comment: No relacionado directamente con tu pregunta: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP, tu código es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse de cara al público. Además, usas funciones mysql_* que se consideran obsoletas y fueron eliminadas del estándar de PHP, por lo que no deberían usarse para evitar problemas.

Comment: Hola buenas tarde por lo que puedo ver es que tu consulta te esta devolviendo null seria bueno solucionar ese problema primero para después ver porque no se te esta cargando el select

Comment: Aníbal, tu pregunta no es clara, y no sé si tienes bien organizado tu código. Imagino que la lógica es la siguiente: 1. Tienes un combobox donde se selecciona el estado, 2. al seleccionarlo lanza un Ajax al archivo `getMunicipio.php` para obtener el municipio... **¿de todos los códigos que muestras, cuál es el de `getMunicipio.php`?** 3. de todo funcionar bien, se carga un combo con los municipios de ese estado, y al seleccionar un municipio, se lanza otro Ajax que llama a `getLocalidad.php`... **¿en tu pregunta, cuál es el código del archivo `getLocalidad.php`**? Indica quién es quien x favor

Comment: Además, en los `POST` tú debes usar el valor que diste a cada elemento en la etiqueta `name` del HTML. Si el select del municipio tiene `name="municipio"`, significa que para recuperar el `value` del municipio seleccionado, debes escribir esto: `$id_municipio = $_POST['municipio'];`. O sea, POST lo que hace es crear un array, donde la clave de cada elemento es el valor de la etiqueta `name` que tenga ese elemento en el DOM (HTML). Es evidente que por la forma que aplicas el POST eso no se ha entendido, pues con el `estado` cometes el mismo error.